# What was 1969's La caduta degli dei (AKA The Damned) original language?

Tags: dialogue, production, dubbing

I'm trying to find out the original language version of Luchino Visconti's film **La caduta degli dei (Götterdämmerung)**. Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Damned_(1969_film)) and [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064118/) list it as "English, German", but I have seen the german version and it sure looks dubbed and poorly lip-synched. I think german is listed only because a particular scene with an homage to Marlene Dietrich in *Der blaue Engel*, so that would leave english as the main original language.

However I have also seen a version in italian, and beign an italian-german production, by an italian film director, with a multicultural cast I would like some confirmation, hopefully in the form of interviews or documentary.

Edit: I found [a review](https://letterboxd.com/vadekawa/film/the-damned/) which also cast doubt on the english version as "original".

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11480/sergio-leones-spaghetti-westerns-english-or-italian