# Determine original language of the movie

Tags: dialogue, film-industry, translation

Sometimes I want to watch some movie in its original language i.e. without translation.

For some movies, it's pretty easy. For example,

- Antonioni's *[Blowup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowup)* was originally filmed in English
- His *[L'Avventura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Avventura)* was originally filmed in Italian

But for some movies it's not easy to determine the original language.

Like, *[Spirits of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirits_of_the_Dead)* by Roger Vadim, Louis Malle and Federico Fellini. How I can determine in what language it was filmed originally: Italian or French?

Another example is *[Beyond the Clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Clouds_(1995_film))* by Michelangelo Antonioni and Wim Wenders. The question is the same: How I can determine in what language it was filmed originally?

Well, currently I'm interested in these two movies, but my question is broader. Is there a way to determine the original language of *any*, i.e. *arbitrary*, movie?

Comment: The first language listed under the 'Language' part on the 'Details' section on a film's IMDb page is often a good indicator, albeit not always fully reliable. Also, some films don't have one original language, but are dubbed to several languages from the start. In such cases I usually prefer the language that most of the main actors speak natively.

Comment: @Steadybox Hm. Probably, we should look at release dates. For example: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114086/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt. Here is shown, that it was firstly released in Italy, then in Germany and then in France. From that, it could be sayed, that the original language is Italian. What you think about it?

Comment: I think it's possible that a film gets made in one language originally, but its first release is dubbed to another language. So the first release date is not an infallible measure either. Besides, it could happen that a film gets released in multiple countries on the same date, and then the release date would offer no resolution.

Comment: @johnc.j. Not a good measure. There are films which were released earlier in "dubbed" countires than in the country of origin. See [Prometheus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ov_inf), as an example of main stream blockbusters.

Comment: @Mouvier Thanks, now it's completely clear for me. Also, for futher readers, to illustrate what Steadybox said ("some films don't have one original language, but are dubbed to several languages from the start") I would add this related link: [Sergio Leone's Spaghetti Westerns: English or Italian?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11480/sergio-leones-spaghetti-westerns-english-or-italian)

Comment: Also, here is another example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Vinti. ("The theatrical film was dubbed into Italian for all three episodes, although the Paris episode is spoken in French, and the London episode in English. The Italian DVD by Medusa Film offers the restored uncut trilingual version.")

Answer (score 5):

One suggestion would be the BBFC website (British Board of Film Censors) that categorizes each film it provides a certificate for.

So, for [Beyond the Clouds](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/search/releases/beyond%2Bthe%2Bclouds), we see the related works that point at

[PAR-DELA LES NUAGES - BEYOND THE CLOUDS](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/releases/par-dela-les-nuages-beyond-clouds-1970)

> Title - PAR-DELA LES NUAGES - BEYOND THE CLOUDS
>   Also known as - BEYOND THE CLOUDS
>   Year - 2009
>   Distributor(s) - Second Sight Films
>   Classified date(s) - 15/05/2009
>   Main language - **French**
>   Submitted run time104m 54s
>   BBFC reference - BVF066043

So, the original here is French.

BBFC doesn't list "Spirits of the Dead", so you'll need some other reference there.  It's doubtful you'll find a single source for every film.  The BBFC does seem pretty dependable though (when it has results).